# How to do join only with distinct items with latest date

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 SELECT t.aerop_salida,
    t.aerop_llegada,
    t.duracion,
    p.precio,
        p.fecha_hora_actualizacion
   FROM tramo t,
    vuelo v,
    tramo_precio p
  WHERE ((t.aerop_salida = v.aerop_salida) AND (t.aerop_llegada = v.aerop_llegada) AND ((p.tramo_aerolinea)::text = (t.aerolinea)::text) AND (p.tramo_aerop_salida = t.aerop_salida) AND (p.tramo_aerop_llegada = t.aerop_llegada));
```

Would output

```
EZE LAX 15:25:00    12399   2017-10-10 19:50:58
EZE LAX 15:25:00    11900   2017-10-17 19:51:29
EZE LAX 16:20:00    12390   2017-10-15 23:55:03
AEP IGR 02:45:00    3200    2017-10-16 10:55:27
IGR LIM 03:15:00    5600    2017-10-11 20:00:41
```

But should only output EZE - LAX trip with price 11900 as this is the current one (was updated on 2017 10 17)

EDIT:

I'm trying something like this but giving me syntax error:

```
 SELECT t.aerop_salida,
    t.aerop_llegada,
    t.duracion,
    p.precio,
        p.fecha_hora_actualizacion
   FROM tramo t,
    vuelo v,
    (select DISTINCT tp.tramo_aerolinea, tp.tramo_aerop_llegada, tp.tramo_aerop_salida FROM tramo_precio tp order by tp.fecha_hora_actualizacion desc) p
  WHERE ((t.aerop_salida = v.aerop_salida) AND (t.aerop_llegada = v.aerop_llegada) AND ((p.tramo_aerolinea)::text = (t.aerolinea)::text) AND (p.tramo_aerop_salida = t.aerop_salida) AND (p.tramo_aerop_llegada = t.aerop_llegada));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is the Twenty-First Century, after all.

You can do what you want using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.aerop_salida, t.aerop_llegada) t.aerop_salida, t.aerop_llegada, t.duracion,
       p.precio, p.fecha_hora_actualizacion
FROM tramo t JOIN
     vuelo v
     ON t.aerop_salida = v.aerop_salida AND
        t.aerop_llegada = v.aerop_llegada JOIN
        tramo_precio p
        ON (p.tramo_aerolinea)::text = (t.aerolinea)::text) AND 
           (p.tramo_aerop_salida = t.aerop_salida) AND 
           (p.tramo_aerop_llegada = t.aerop_llegada)
ORDER BY t.aerop_salida, t.aerop_llegada, p.fecha_hora_actualizacion DESC;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks. I just realized that it isn't showing all available flights. Could you help me?
If there are two Vuelos (flights) like EZE - LAX, the only thing I need is that the price is the same for both, being it the last one in tramo_precio

Comment: I figured out thse dont have any tramo_price set for that key

Comment: s/JOIN clause/FROM clause/

Comment: @JorgeeFG . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.  I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: @GordonLinoff its ok, it wasn't showing all flights in the Vuelo table, but it was because some Tramos (Segment, and Fligths fly segments) didn't have an assigned price in Tramos_precio

Answer (score 0):

if col3 contains the date column

```
select * from A 
inner join 
(select distinct t.col1, t. col2 
 from
    (select col1, col2, col3
     from table
     grouping by col1, col2
     having max(col3)
     ) t
)outer
on a.col1 = outer.col1
```